# Swift Save/Reload data to plist

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

I entered my samplePlist.plist in the project folder and I'm trying to save the data on this .....

```
 var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) //Get Path of Documents Directory
        var documentsDirectory:AnyObject = paths[0]
        var path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("samplePlist.plist")
        var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var fileExists:Bool = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)
        var data : NSMutableDictionary?
        //Check if plist file exists at path specified
        if fileExists == false {
            //File does not exists
            data = NSMutableDictionary () //Create data dictionary for storing in plist      
        } else  {
            //File exists – retrieve data from plist inside data dictionary
            data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        }
        data?.setValue("\(countButton)", forKey: "NumeroButton")
        data?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true) //Write data to file permanently
```

and i Read to the plist

```
//Get path of Documents directory
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory:AnyObject = paths[0]
     var path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("samplePlist.plist")
//Retrieve contents from file at specified path
    var data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
   println(path)
```

my problem is that ,if I try to start it on my iphone ,I do not upload the file to the My Documents folder on startup of the Application

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9CCDBD0B-FA29-4C9E-910E-9AD5F5B11E5A/Documents/samplePlist.plist
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Is it crashing on this line: `data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)` ?

Comment: No my problem is that I do not upload the file to the My Documents folder on startup of the Application

Comment: if i manually load the file to the My Documents folder all is well

Comment: Try: `NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(_:, inDomains: )` to get the file path. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html